# How exactly should one use declttype to deduce the return type of a function which returns a class instance instantiated over template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, decltype

We have a basic function which adds 2 floats(to certain degree of accuracy).

```
  float add(float x, float y)
  {
  std::cout << "\n in the add function \n";
  float res = x+y;
  std::cout << "\n exiting the add function \n";
  return res;
  }
```

We have, a forward declaration,

```
template <typename> struct Logger;
```

followed by, implementation,

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Logger<R(Args...)>
{
    // these  would be members 
  function<R(Args...)> func; 
  string name;

   // this would be ctor 
  Logger(const function<R(Args...)>& func, const string& name)
    :
      func{func},
      name{name}
  {

  }
    // this would be the overload fun operator 
  R  operator() (Args ...args) const 
  {
    cout << "\n Entering Into ... .......\n" << name << endl; 
    R result = func(args...); //  this would be actual call to the basic      function 
    cout << "\n Exiting from  ...  \n" << name << endl; 
    return result; //  this would be of type R, the return from the function call

  }
};
```

We then have a function,

```
// This function would provide an instantiation of 
// the Logger class, 
// and that would call the ctor of the Logger class 
template <typename R, typename... Args>
auto make_logger(R (*func)(Args...), const string& name ) 
{
  return Logger<R(Args...)>{

    std::function<R(Args...)>(func),
    name
  };

}
// Notice, there is no decltype in the above function, and I would like to use 
// the decltype, I am aware that decltype cannot be used on packed template argument
```

// Here is the use of the API, in some main function

```
auto logger_add = make_logger(add, "**Adding Numbers**");
auto result = logger_add(2.0, 3.0);
```

Problem:

Can one make the above code work in C++11? Specifically, using declytype, how would one use the make_logger function.

Notes:
I am following a book, and the above code is taken from, 
https://github.com/Apress/design-patterns-in-modern-cpp/blob/master/Structural/Decorator/decorator.cpp

Comment: Why use decltype at all here? You *name* the type you return.

Comment: I am looking for auto func() -> int
type syntax for make_logger function

Comment: So...`auto make_logger() -> Logger<R(Args...)>`. You don't even need the trailing return type, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

You had some typos preventing your code to compile both with C++11 and C++17. The consequence of that typo was `R` to be deduced as the function's type instead of the return type ;)

Fix:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
auto make_logger(R (*func)(Args...), const std::string& name )  -> Logger<R, Args...>
{
    return Logger<R, Args...> { std::function<R(Args...)>(func), name };
}
```

Full demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e9e5cf6d29669c4

Comment: You change signature of the class, which was valid.

Answer (score 1):

As state in comment, you already provide type, so it would be

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
auto make_logger(R (*func)(Args...), const string& name ) 
-> Logger<R(Args...)>
{
  return { std::function<R(Args...)>(func), name };
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d61c3e6c69cceb38)

Personally, I would write the whole class, something like:

```
template<typename F>
class Logger
{
private:
    F func; 
    std::string name;
public:
    Logger(const F& func, const std::string& name) :
      func{func},
      name{name}
    {}

    template <typename ... Args>    
    auto  operator() (Args&& ...args) const
    -> decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        std::cout << "\n Entering Into ... .......\n" << name << std::endl;
        struct Finally {
            Finally(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}
            ~Finally() { std::cout << "\n Exiting from  ...  \n" << name << std::endl; }
            const std::string& name;
        } finally{name};
        return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename F>
Logger<typename std::decay<F>::type>
make_logger(const F& func, const std::string& name)
{
  return { func, name };
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5e36bd4823bc60d)